# Why do these Objective-C and Swift subclasses behave differently?

Tags: objective-c, uibutton, swift

I have the two following classes in my project:

Objective C *(sans header file)*:

```
#import "CircleButton.h"

@implementation CircleButton

-(id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)aDecoder {
    self = [super initWithCoder:aDecoder];
    self.layer.borderColor = [[UIColor whiteColor] CGColor];
    self.layer.borderWidth = 3;
    self.layer.cornerRadius = self.frame.size.width / 2;
    return self;
}

@end
```

Swift:

```
import Foundation

class CircleButton : UIButton {
    init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder!) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
        self.layer.borderColor = UIColor.whiteColor().CGColor
        self.layer.borderWidth = 3
        self.layer.cornerRadius = self.frame.size.width / 2
    }
}
```

As far as I can tell, they are identical, but when I use them on a series of buttons in Interface Builder, the Swift implementation only draws the white circle border around the first button. When using the Objective C implementation, all buttons have the circle border. What do I need to do to make my Swift file behave like the Objective C one?

#### Update:

I just noticed I'm also getting the following error message in the logs:

`Unknown class CircleButton in Interface Builder file.`

This appears N-1 times, where N is the number of times I used the Swift version of the file in my Storyboard.

Comment: What does UIColor.colorWithHex do?

Comment: Ah, that's a category. Just returns a UIColor. I'll replace it with `UIColor.whiteColor()`.

Comment: Your swift code works fine on a new project with 3 buttons (although `import Foundation` should be `import UIKit`). Are you sure that you have set your custom class on all buttons? Update: Reproduced your error by providing a non existing module, so check your module setting also on IB.

Comment: can you paste the xib as xml?

Comment: @Alladinian I only have one module, so it should have auto detected that. However, when I manually set the module, it did work. Please add as an answer and I'll upvote/accept!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I was able to reproduce the error you're seeing after changing the module on the buttons to something that doesn't exist.

So make sure that the module is set correctly in IB. This explains also why the obj-c code works while swift fails.